# What is enough to qualify a question as spam?

Tags: discussion, triage, spam

I've encountered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62344565/need-help-web-scraping-by-using-soup-payton) during triage.  It does include a hyperlink to a commercial website which makes me think that I should mark it as spam.  However, it is a legitimate question about web scraping, so perhaps the poster was providing the link to show what kind of data he's trying to parse.

Should I still flag it?

Comment: that is definitely no spam, he doesn't promote cars, he wants to "grab"the dataa and use it for what ever purpose.

Comment: That’s what I thought.  However, I just recovered from a review suspension and didn’t want to take any chances.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Despite the presence of the link—which, I'll grant, does smell kind of spammy—it is a legitimate attempt to ask a programming question. If you read past the link, you'll see that the person is trying to ask about scraping data from the site.

That means a "spam" flag is unwarranted. If you did flag it as spam, the most likely scenario is that a moderator would mark your flag as "disputed". At least, that's what I'd do, recognizing why you thought to flag it as spam, but deciding upon further inspection that it is not truly spam and thus the penalties associated with spam should not be applied.

**A better course of action would be to flag the question as unsuitable for this site (needs to be closed).** In Triage, this is the button labeled "Unsalvageable". While not spam, there isn't enough information there to meet our requirements. There's no language tag, there's no [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and it's not clear enough.

Since you mention Triage and having recently been suspended from reviewing, I'll point out that the biggest mistake folks make in Triage is choosing "Requires Editing" in cases like this. As the detailed description tells you, "Requires Editing" is only for when the post can be edited into shape by regular community members. If it needs edits from the original author, then that's "Unsalvageable". And, as always, if you're unsure, it's OK to "Skip". Thanks for asking and attempting to improve!

Comment: It looks ok to me, without the link he must post the html code of that side, that would be ahrd, when it is dynamic.

Comment: Yes, that's why you need to create a minimal, reproducible example. A link to external code/site is never sufficient.